# Regular expression for detecting first name and/or last name

Tags: html, design-patterns, text, input

Please help me to build a pattern in the text input field like that,

```
<input name="BusinessOwner" type="text" id="BusinessOwner" pattern="?">
```

But the rule is that this input field only allow English **Small letter** and/or **Capital letter**(include/Exclude space) and no **Numeric Digits**. So according to the rule,

```
Adam Smith => valid
adam => valid
AB CD => valid
abcd12 => Invalid
abcd 12 => Invalid
```

Please help me to build the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use this pattern:

```
^([A-Za-z]+[,.]?[ ]?|[A-Za-z]+['-]?)+$
```

Final:

```
<input name="BusinessOwner" type="text" id="BusinessOwner" pattern="^([A-Za-z]+[,.]?[ ]?|[A-Za-z]+['-]?)+$">
```

Hope this would be helpfull.

Comment: How can i add the character length of your given pattern character length is less than 25 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyCode` to restrict on input ..It won't allow you to enter number..This is basic logic you can modify as per your condition

```js
jQuery.fn.forceNumeric = function() {

  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).keydown(function(e) {
      var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

      if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey &&   key > 64 && key <= 123 || (key==32 || key ==8)
)
        return true;

      return false;
    });
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".numberinput").forceNumeric();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="txtNumber1" id="txtNumber1" value="" class="numberinput" />
```

FYI http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

**UPDATE**

```js
$(function() {

    $("#field").bind("keyup", function(event) {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
        if (regex.test($("#field").val())) {
            $('.validation').html('valid');
        } else {
            $('.validation').html("not valid");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field" />

<div class="validation"></div>
```

Or

```
<input name="lorem" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/g,'');">
```

I think you will need jquery or javascript for regex..

Comment: Only i need pattern(regular expression) not javascript or jQuery code segment. Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I know the answer only in php

```
$str =$_POST['BusinessOwner'];
if (preg_match('#[0-9]#',$str))
  {
  echo 'number not allowed';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler regex than the accepted answer.

`^[a-zA-Z\s]+$` - allows any character from A-Z, a-z and space 
`^[a-zA-Z\s]{3,20}$` - allows any character from A-Z, a-z and space, with min and max length of 3 and 20 respectively.
`^([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+$` - allows any character from A-Z, a-z and a single space only between the words.